# Efficient way to update all rankings of a table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Hope this question makes sense. Suppose we have a table of the top 1,000,000 most visited websites on the internet. The table would look something like this.

| Name | Address | Visits | Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Example Site | example.com | 1000000000 | 1 |
| Stack Overflow | stackoverflow.com | 900000000 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Small Site | smallsite.com | 100 | 999999 |
| Tiny Site | tinysite.com | 1 | 1000000 |

Each week we check how many site visits each site had, and depending on the site visits we update their ranking. If we had a site that blew up in the past week and went say from rank 900,000 to 1,000, what is the most efficient way to update all the rows affected in the table? As they would need to be bumped up by 1.

Is there a concept in SQL that would allow us to make large batch changes like that without locking out the table?

Obviously this doesn't take into consideration all the other changes in rankings, but wanted to keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: When dealing with large scale databases and datasets like this, I like to use a 3rd party system for "indexing" the data --  Something like [SOLR](https://solr.apache.org/) will index your database, and during the indexing you can give it "rules" so that the indexing engine itself will assign the "ranks" when the index is performed.  Once indexed .. You'll be using SOLR to query your results instead of SQL since it's basically just an XML copy of your database ..  You'll set the index on a cron to be performed every x days/hours/weeks ..

Comment: every update takes time, you can not circumvent it, but you can make a second table wiith the new ran, and copy the data im small chunks, so that the lock time will be reduce

Comment: Maybe don't save rank to table, calculate it when needed. Is ranking determined by more than just the number of visits? If not, just sort and use Row_Number() to assign sequential number.